# Is a simple time series one- or two-dimensional?

Tags: time-series, dataset

Say we have a simple monthly time series:

```
> ldeaths
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
1974 3035 2552 2704 2554 2014 1655 1721 1524 1596 2074 2199 2512
1975 2933 2889 2938 2497 1870 1726 1607 1545 1396 1787 2076 2837
1976 2787 3891 3179 2011 1636 1580 1489 1300 1356 1653 2013 2823
1977 3102 2294 2385 2444 1748 1554 1498 1361 1346 1564 1640 2293
1978 2815 3137 2679 1969 1870 1633 1529 1366 1357 1570 1535 2491
1979 3084 2605 2573 2143 1693 1504 1461 1354 1333 1492 1781 1915
```

Is it one- or two-dimensional? The values are of course one-dimensional, but since we have information about the time, do we consider a simple time-series as this one as **two-dimensional data**?

Comment: I wouldn't call a single time series like this two-dimensional. You need two dimensions to plot these data, but I doubt that there is any other sense in which statistical people would call them two-dimensional. In statistics, you count dimensions according to how many variables there are of the same kind. Time here is an index rather than a separate measurement or count. I am not sure that much hinges on the answer, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the practical sense.
Though the set is indeed ordered and has an index set, in practical applications the mechanics of this are already in the methodology. For example you have your time series model which already provides the tools to step through the series by using vector and matrix operations. At times you can see that the order is actually not even relevant.
Of course it is possible for some operations to depend on the time but if that happens it turns out to become a separate variable or entity. If you'd ever calculate something with the monthly series of.. months... you'd create probably a new categorical or interpolated set of numbers for this, for example if you'd include a trend variable.

Theoretically the answer must be something else:
For some or many things the fact that information about time and value are an ordered set may be of relevance. Clearly the time series is not the same without that information. It is missing and wether  or not it is of practical use is not relevant to the fact that a) it is missing and b) there are possible uses.
Indeed without the second dimension it is no longer ordered. It can be ordered but then only by size or some other parameter. If you order by time, you NEED an association or order between these two dimensions.

So I'd say in the context of working with the set, it is one dimensionally but ordered. Theoretically this doesn't exist, it is an ordered set with an index of months or integers or whatever but the data is two dimensional.